# Minkowski's dot product

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, metric-tensor, dimensional-analysis

I am trying to deduce the Minkowski's dot product for two dimentional space:
$$g=x^1y^1-c^2t_xt_y$$
If $f$ denote the Lorentz's transformation for two dimentional case:
$$\begin{array}{rcll}
f:&\mathbb{R}&\longrightarrow &\mathbb{R}\\
&x&\longmapsto &f(x)=\Lambda x
\end{array}\qquad \text{ with }\
\Lambda = \gamma\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 &-v\\
-v/c^2 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$
 we have to find a matrix:
$$G=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
g_{11} & g_{12}\\
g_{21} & g_{22}
\end{array}\right)$$
such that $\chi^tG\chi= (\Lambda \chi)^tG(\Lambda \chi)$ or equivalently:
$$G=\Lambda ^tG\Lambda$$
we get the system:
$$\begin{array}{rlr}
\frac{v^2}{c^2}g_{11}-\frac{v}{c^2}g_{12}-\frac{v}{c^2}g_{21}+\frac{v^2}{c^4}g_{22}&=0&(1)\\
-vg_{11}+\frac{v^2}{c^2}g_{12}+\frac{v^2}{c^2}g_{21}-\frac{v}{c^2}g_{22}&=0& (2)\\
-vg_{11}+\frac{v^2}{c^2}g_{12}+\frac{v^2}{c^2}g_{21}-\frac{v}{c^2}g_{22}&=0& (3)\\
v^2g_{12}-vg_{12}-vg_{21}+\frac{v^2}{c^2}g_{22}&=0&(4) 
\end{array}$$
which is equivalent to:
$$\begin{array}{rll}
vg_{11}-g_{12}-g_{21}+\frac{v}{c^2}g_{22}&=0\\
c^2g_{11}-vg_{12}-vg_{21}+g_{22}&=0
\end{array}$$
if we denote $g_{21}=\lambda$ and $g_{22}=\mu$, it's easy to prove that:
$$G=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-\mu/c^2& -\lambda\\
\lambda &\mu
\end{array}\right)$$
As $G$ must be symmetric, $\lambda=0$; so then:
$$G=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-\mu/c^2& 0\\
0 &\mu
\end{array}\right)$$
My question is:

*How we can get that $\mu$ must be $-c^2$?*

Comment: Minkowski's metric is the definition of Minkowski's metric... What do you want to "deduce" the definition from? The only derivation one can do is from the requirement that c is the same in every inertial system... which leads to the Lorentz transformations and the metric from a physical point of view. c is just a choice of units, anyway, so you might as well make it 1.

Comment: related: [Why does the Lorentz transformation in special relativity have to be like this?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15142/)

Comment: Hi FUUNK1000. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can't deduce this, because all metrics with different $\mu$ are invariant under Lorentz transformations.

The best you can do is to choose the units in which you measure the invariant interval such that $\mu$ is equal to whatever you like it to be.

Comment: Actually it is possible to deduce this and is a standard exercise in these lecture notes, see pg.40 after eq. (3.41): https://users.physics.ox.ac.uk/~smithb/website/coursenotes/rel_A.pdf

Comment: @FUUNK1000 Consider the invariance relationship as applied to the space time-interval: for an event $(ct, x)$ it is known that $(ct, x)G(ct, x)^T = (ct)^2 - x^2$.

Comment: @udrv I dont understand your notation, but consider plugging $2g_{\mu \nu}$ instead of $g_{\mu \nu}$ in your formulas for the invariant interval. What would change exactly?

Comment: I had in mind matrix notation, with $G$ a $2\times 2$ matrix and $(ct, x)$ as it reads, a 2d row vector. This makes the transposed $(ct, x)^T$ the column vector. Explicitly, $$\left(\begin{array}{cc} ct & x \end{array}\right)\left( \begin{array}{cc} g_{11} & g_{12} \\ g_{21} & g_{22} \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array} {c} ct \\ x \end{array}\right) = (ct)^2 - x^2$$

Comment: Then using $g_{\mu\nu} \rightarrow 2g_{\mu\nu}$ or $G \rightarrow 2G$ should give $$2\left(\begin{array}{cc} ct & x \end{array}\right)\left( \begin{array}{cc} g_{11} & g_{12} \\ g_{21} & g_{22} \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array} {c} ct \\ x \end{array}\right) = (ct)^2 - x^2$$ If you have in mind that $G = \Lambda^T G \Lambda$ is invariant under a rescaling of $G$, then yes, the space-time interval condition fixes the metric's scale.